# CSS. Apply style on a section only

Tags: css

I have this style:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

And it is for the carousel only, how can i just apply it to the carousel section and not the hole document?

I tried selecting the section using .section-home class but it did not work, i couldnt figure out a way to do it, and i can not use body, and html selectors because they ruin the rest of the page

The Html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>| AQUASafe</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/main.css" />
  

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick-theme.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/helpers.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/aos.css">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark probootstrap_navbar probootstrap_scrolled-light fixed-top" id="probootstrap-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="probootstrap-menu"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="probootstrap-menu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#section-home">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#asection-bout">QUI SOMME NOUS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#section-metiers">NOS MÉTIERS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#section-services">SERVICES
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#section-products">PRODUITS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#section-contact">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- END nav -->

    <!-- Carousel 2 -->
    <section class="scroll main-carousel" id="section-home">
    <div class="slider-container ">
        <div class="slider-control left inactive "></div>
        <div class="slider-control right "></div>
        <ul class="slider-pagi "></ul>
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide slide-0 active ">
            <div class="slide__bg"></div>
            <div class="slide__content ">
              <svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
                <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
              </svg>
              <div class="slide__text text-carousel">
                <h2 class="slide__text-heading ">Project name 1</h2>
                <p class="slide__text-desc ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia.</p>
                <a class="slide__text-link ">Project link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide slide-1 ">
            <div class="slide__bg"></div>
            <div class="slide__content ">
              <svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
                <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
              </svg>
              <div class="slide__text">
                <h2 class="slide__text-heading">Project name 2</h2>
                <p class="slide__text-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia.</p>
                <a class="slide__text-link">Project link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide slide-2">
            <div class="slide__bg"></div>
            <div class="slide__content">
              <svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
                <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
              </svg>
              <div class="slide__text">
                <h2 class="slide__text-heading">Project name 3</h2>
                <p class="slide__text-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia.</p>
                <a class="slide__text-link">Project link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
      <!--ENd Carousel 2 -->

    <!-- About section -->
    <section class="probootstrap-section-half d-md-flex scroll" id="section-about">
        <div class="probootstrap-text">
            <div class="probootstrap-inner probootstrap-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
                <h2 class="heading mb-4">QUI SOMME NOUS</h2>
                <p>AQUASafe est une entreprise de service et de développement de solutions technologiques, précurseur dans les
                    services liés à l’environnement et à la qualité de l’eau.
                </p>
                <p>Nos solutions, développées autour de l’Internet Des Objets (appliquée dans le secteur industrielles), sont
                    destinées aux entreprises et organismes pour leurs faciliter la collecte, transmission, et visualisation
                    à distance de données, leurs permettant ainsi de réagir rapidement en cas de besoin.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="probootstrap-image probootstrap-animate" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" style="background-image: url(assets/img/img1.jpg)">
        </div>

    </section>
    <!-- END About section -->


    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollify.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
            AOS.init();
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.scrollify({
                section : ".scroll",
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us also your HTML.

Comment: you can use css selector for the same

Comment: The hole page or just the carousel section?

Comment: @ Andrzej Ziółek I added the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You would need to name your css to the name of your corousel example below if your carousel is in a Div for example

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

.myCarousel::before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  }
```

Comment: It did not work too, shouldn't we use # to select Id instead of . ?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you're referring *Carousel 2 Section*

```
<section class="scroll main-carousel" id="section-home">
```

To apply the CSS styles to this section only, use

```css
section .main-carousel {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll main-carousel" id="section-home">
    <div class="slider-container ">
        <div class="slider-control left inactive "></div>
        <div class="slider-control right "></div>
        <ul class="slider-pagi "></ul>
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide slide-0 active ">
            <div class="slide__bg"></div>
            <div class="slide__content ">
              <svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
                <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
              </svg>
              <div class="slide__text text-carousel">
                <h2 class="slide__text-heading ">Project name 1</h2>
                <p class="slide__text-desc ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia.</p>
                <a class="slide__text-link ">Project link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide slide-1 ">
            <div class="slide__bg"></div>
            <div class="slide__content ">
              <svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
                <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
              </svg>
              <div class="slide__text">
                <h2 class="slide__text-heading">Project name 2</h2>
                <p class="slide__text-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia.</p>
                <a class="slide__text-link">Project link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide slide-2">
            <div class="slide__bg"></div>
            <div class="slide__content">
              <svg class="slide__overlay" viewBox="0 0 720 405" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax slice">
                <path class="slide__overlay-path" d="M0,0 150,0 500,405 0,405" />
              </svg>
              <div class="slide__text">
                <h2 class="slide__text-heading">Project name 3</h2>
                <p class="slide__text-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio veniam minus illo debitis nihil animi facere, doloremque voluptate tempore quia.</p>
                <a class="slide__text-link">Project link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is this a copy-paste code? I think you're missing some CSS code for your carousel.